# C++ template accept only typenames with certain member

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I'm learning how to use templates. Let's say, I have following structure of classes. I'm using the template just for classes `tC` and `tD`(with intention of implementing more similar classes in the future). In other parts of the project I'm using only methods from the base class `A` for abstraction. These classes compile and run correctly in VS2019.

My questions are:

- Is it acceptable(according to guidelines and common sense) to refer in the template class to member of the typename T? (I mean implementation of `getVersion()`)
- Can I specify somehow that typename T requires to have such member?

```cpp
struct version {
    const char* name;
    int date;
};

class A {
    virtual void f() = 0;
    virtual const version& getVersion() const = 0;
}

template <typename T>
class B : public A {
   // some methods implementation specific for class B that require using typename T

   void f() override; // implemented somewhere else
   const version& getVersion() const { return T.v; }
}

class tC {
   static constexpr version v{"tC", 1};
   // some methods for C
}

class tD {
   static constexpr version v{"tD", 2};
   // some methods for D
}
```

Comment: There are several issues here which may be destracting from the actual question: class/struct declarations not ended with `;`, no virtual destructor in base class `A`, trying to override non-virtual functions in the base class, trying declare something `constexpr` that's not allowed to receive this modifier (at least not for C++ <= 17), declaring functions that are supposed to be overridden in the subclass private, privately inheriting a class with (if I guess your intention correctly) purely virtual functions...

Comment: Here is a minimal compiling example.  Unfortunately, it works, which means I have no idea what the original question was asking. https://onlinegdb.com/raF_cbBwN   To make it compile I needed to change the std::string into a character array so that the constexpr would be valid, and I also make the overridden functions virtual in the base, and I made the pieces public so they could be seen, and a couple other things like that.

Comment: Yes, all of these elements are in original code. I generalized too much, sorry for that. Edited the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two questions:

- Is it acceptable to refer in the template class to member of the typename T? (I mean implementation of getVersion())
- Can I specify somehow that typename T requires to have such member?

The answer to both is "yes"

After I made your code into a compilable example, it does both of those things (try removing the definition of v from tD to see it reject that class)

Here is the code I came up with:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct version {
    char name[200];
    int date;
};

class A {
public:
    virtual void f() = 0;
    virtual const version& getVersion() const = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class B : public A {
public:
   // some methods implementation specific for class B that require using typename T

   void f() override {};
   const version& getVersion() const override { return T::v; }
};

class tC {
public:
   static constexpr version v{"tC", 1};
   // some methods for C
};

class tD {
public:
   static constexpr version v{"tD", 2};
   // some methods for D
};

int main()
{
    B<tC> btc;
    version vtc = btc.getVersion();
    printf("%s %d\n",vtc.name,vtc.date);

    B<tD> btd;
    version vtd = btd.getVersion();
    printf("%s %d\n",vtd.name,vtd.date);

    return 0;
}
```

Try it here: https://onlinegdb.com/raF_cbBwN

Comment: So just changing to T::v makes v required for a type?

Comment: No.  `T::v` is how you access a static member of any type - even a normal non-template class.  You could have also used `T().v` which creates a temporary object of `T` and then calls the member.  You can't call a member of a class if you don't have an object.  Try just running `tC.v` - it won't work because `.` doesn't work on types.  But `tC::v` would work and `tC c;` followed by `c.v` would work and so would `tC().v`

Comment: @PrestigeDrom Sorry if my last comment didn't notify you - I forgot to put your name on it.  Anyway, an example of what I said is https://onlinegdb.com/BkBAShYZO

Comment: Ok, thanks! So my question was stupid, then. Just wanted too know whether I'm breaking any c++ guidelines, even though it compiles. Thanks for spending time on my question.

Comment: @PrestigeDrom I don't think it was a stupid question.  I guess I just didn't understand why you were asking.